# Issue for facet wrap function

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, visualization, facet

I'd like to separate my result into two different plot using the facet wrap function, however, my codes seems to give me faulty plots where two different factors (genotype PsbS and T259D) were still shown in the plot despite the data of only one was being shown (This might sound confusing, please refer to my plots). Thanks! [my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWhjb.png)

```
RE <- read_csv("Cq.csv")
view(RE)
data.frame(RE)
ggplot(data=RE, mapping = aes(x = factor(genotype), y = cq, fill= line))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(data=RE, aes(ymin=cq-SEM, ymax=cq+SEM), width=.2, position=position_dodge(width= 0.9))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15))+
  facet_wrap(~genotype)


data.frame(RE)
   id genotype   line           cq       SEM
1   1     PsbS   L1.1 14.870601010 5.4970515
2   2     PsbS   L1.2 23.455655780 1.4763615
3   3     PsbS   L1.3 14.004065480 0.8800974
4   4     PsbS   L1.4  6.888686944 0.5056124
5   5     PsbS   L1.5  8.986116514 0.9482289
6   6     PsbS   L1.6  0.000703389 0.0000864
7   7     PsbS   L1.7 11.422758140 0.3682201
8   8     PsbS   L1.8  7.329694392 0.8226627
9   9     PsbS   L1.9  6.795220106 0.7286420
10 10    T259D L3.3.1 20.549244950 1.6416835
11 11    T259D L3.3.2 24.979360100 4.5510392
12 12    T259D L3.3.3 25.089471950 3.4598942
```

Comment: You have the same variable `genotype` as x-axis and as facet.

Comment: This is because your X-axis is, by default, identical in all facets. Use `~ facet.wrap(~ genotype, scales="free")`

Comment: @MarBlo: No. If they used `line` as the X variable the result would be similar.

Comment: @January: `scales="free_x"` is sufficient to get rid of unused categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ facet.wrap(~ genotype, scales="free")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).